# What am I doing wrong? NSFileManager woes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata, nsfilemanager, nscoding

I'm currently building quite a large iPhone application. Bigger than I expected anyway. But that is beside the point, the overall idea of the application is to grab JSON from a web service, sort it all into custom NSObject's that are linked together and then present.

This goes all well and good. But, because I want the user to be able to see this information on the device without an internet connection, I need to save the information that I am presenting into the Documents folder that each Application has.

I basically implemented the NSCoding protocol into all the custom NSObject's that would need it in order to save it into a subdirectory of the Documents directory.

This is all achieved through this function here.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
     NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data"];
     NSString *dataFileString = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Company.archive"];

     if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataFileString]) //Does directory already exist?
     {

          MACompany *company = [MACompany sharedMACompany];

          NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
          NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
          NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data"];

          NSError *error;
          if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])  //Does directory already exist?
          {
               if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath
                                       withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                        attributes:nil
                                                             error:&error])
               {

            NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
               }
           }

           NSString *dataFileString = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Company.archive"];

           NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
           NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];          
           [archiver encodeObject:company forKey:@"MACompany"];
           [archiver finishEncoding];

           [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:dataFileString
                                            contents:data
                                          attributes:nil];

           [archiver release];
           [data release];

     } else {

      NSLog(@"File already exists, no need to recreate, not yet anyway");

     }

}
```

I do the following request when the user first loads the application (`application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) and when the user opens the application after being in the background (`applicationWillEnterForeground:`).

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data"];
NSString *dataFileString = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Company.archive"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataFileString])  //Does directory already exist?
{
    NSLog(@"Create a new Company Request");

    MAWebRequests *companyReq = [[MAWebRequests alloc] init];
    [companyReq getCompanyDetails];
    [companyReq release];

} else {

    NSLog(@"Saved Company Needs to be Decoded applicationWillEnterForeground");

    MACompany *company = [MACompany sharedMACompany];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data"];

    NSString *dataFileString = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Company.archive"];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataFileString];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    [data release];

    company = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"MACompany"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    [unarchiver release];        


}
```

Now this works all well and good and I can pull from this file also. But, I can only grab the data stored in this file when I have Xcode's debugger attached to the application. As soon as is stopped, the data is corrupted and doesn't include the original data.

The data is still stored there, I can see the created file, but the actual data itself that is stored within the file is wrong...

Should I not be using the above logic to save the data to the file and then pull recreate the shared object?
Has anyone else tried to do such a thing and had success?
Is there any reason as to why I'm running into this weird issue?
Has anyone else had this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, have been trying all sorts of different methods to get it to work and nothing has been able to get there. All I need to be able to do is be able to store the data there permanently until I need to update it...

Comment: `[MAWebRequests alloc];` sounds bad. Did you forget to `init` it? Also, if you need to persist large amount of data between launch, you should consider using CoreData or SQLite...

Comment: I did forget to init, thank you! Cleaned that bit up, but still doesn't resolve my issue... Have tracked the size of data that I am saving, 3kb, not big at all! :)

Comment: OK, please update your post accordingly. Anyway the code you already pasted here looks OK. You need to post the code which encodes and decodes things. You should also run "Analyze" in Xcode (available below the Build menu) and correct your code to remove all the warnings.

Comment: Is it possible that your saving code simply takes too long to complete. The OS gives you only a few seconds to return from `applicationDidEnterBackground:` before it will kill your app for being unresponsive (unless the debugger is attached).

Comment: @OleBegemann I think you might be right, going to try and implement it elsewhere to encode and save the menu. Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't matter too much where you do it in your app's lifecycle. If saving blocks the UI for a significant amount of time, you not only risk being killed by the OS, it also means a pretty bad user experience. Maybe you should consider whether you can move the saving process into the background.

Comment: Alright, obviously there is still a lot of research needed to be done and need to work everything out as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by saving the MACompany object well before applicationDidEnterBackground:

Major thanks to @OleBegemann for his aid in finding where the issue nested.